# Sorting input numbers in batch file

Tags: sorting, batch-file

Im trying to create a program in which you will enter **5 numbers** randomly and will automatically **shows the sorted** entered numbers from **lowest to highest**. Here is my code.

```
@echo off

:main

    set /p num1="Enter 1st :"
    set /p num2="Enter 2nd :"
    set /p num3="Enter 3rd :"
    set /p num4="Enter 4th :"
    set /p num5="Enter 5th :"
    set /a high=0
    set /a low=0


    set /a ave=(num1+num2+num3+num4+num5)/5

    if %num1% GTR %num2% (set /a high=%num1%) ELSE set /a high =%num2%
    if %num3% GTR %high% (set /a high=%num3%) 
    if %num4% GTR %high% (set /a high=%num4%) 
    if %num5% GTR %high% (set /a high=%num5%) 

    if %num1% LSS %num2% (set /a low=%num1%) ELSE set /a low =%num2%
    if %num3% LSS %low% (set /a low=%num3%) 
    if %num4% LSS %low% (set /a low=%num4%) 
    if %num5% LSS %low% (set /a low=%num5%) 


    ECHO.
    ECHO Average: %ave%
    ECHO Highest: %high%
    ECHO Lowest: %low%
    ECHO Input Numbers: %num1%    %num2%    %num3%    %num4%    %num5%

:end

set /p return="Continue?"

    if "%return%"=="yes" GOTO main 
    GOTO exit   

:exit
```

Comment: nice. is there a question?

Comment: How can I sort the 5 numbers? That's my problem.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to solve this problem. In the "one by one" method each variable must be compared vs. another one; this method is too much complex and is the one you used to read the values. You may also use `sort` command to sort the numbers (as Rafael tried in his answer); however, the numbers must be padded at left side with zeros in order to be correctly sorted.

When a certain process is repeated over several elements, the usual way to solve such a problem is via an *array*. You may find descriptions about array concept in several sites, like [in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_type). You may read how to use arrays in a Batch file at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990).

The Batch file below make good use of the fact that environment variables are kept automatically sorted; this way, the program just insert the numbers in an array and then take out its elements, so the sort process itself is not required:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set N=5

:main

    rem Delete array elements from previous cycle, if any:
    for /F "delims==" %%a in ('set array[ 2^>NUL') do set "%%a="

    rem Read the numbers; at same time, accumulate they in "ave" variable
    rem and create the array with the proper index (with left zeros)
    set ave=0
    for /L %%i in (1,1,%N%) do (
        set /P num="Enter number %%i :"
        set /A ave+=num
        set index=000000000!num!
        set array[!index:~-10!]=!num!
    )

    set /A ave=ave/N

    rem Assemble the output line and get low and high values
    set "output="
    set "low="
    for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('set array[') do (
        if not defined low set low=%%a
        set high=%%a
        set output=!output!   %%a
    )

    ECHO/
    ECHO Average: %ave%
    ECHO Highest: %high%
    ECHO Lowest: %low%
    ECHO Input Numbers: %output%

    set /p return="Continue?"

if "%return%"=="yes" GOTO main
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an answer to a similar "sort numbers" question, and want to add example of using SORT command as an alternative for completeness. Note that using SORT requires writing a file to disk and seems less efficient:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "num_1=2" & set "num_2=5" & set "num_3=1" & set "num_4=18" & set "num_5=10"

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%i in ('set num_') do (set /a "var=1000000+%%i"
    echo !var! >> nums.txt)
for /f %%j in ('sort nums.txt') do (set /a "var=%%j-1000000"
    set "nums=!nums! !var!")
del /q nums.txt & echo !nums!

:eol
```